# adding a link to a file in the message of a failed MSTest unit test

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, mstest, markup

I have some MSTest unit tests where, when the test fails, I display a path to a file with more information about the failure.  I show the full file path, starting with "C:\", but Visual Studio doesn't display that as a clickable link.  It seems possible for that to be a clickable link, because right below the failure message when I view the test results in Visual Studio, there's an "Error Stack Trace" section with clickable links to the lines in the code where failures occurred.  I tried making my test's failure message include `<a href='c:\my_file.txt'>c:\my_file.txt</a>` but that doesn't work--the source shows.  When I look at the .trx file that gets created when I do a test run, the contents of TestRun > Results > UnitTestResult > Output > Message includes `&lt;a href='c:\my_file.txt'&gt;c:\my_file.txt&lt;/a&gt;`.  Is there any kind of markup that Visual Studio understands for the contents of the `Message` node in a .trx file such that I could make a clickable link appear in the Visual Studio test results?